# Comment traduire « what has been seen cannot be unseen » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions

Après le visionnage d'un film particulièrement... comment dire, extrême/choquant/bizarre, je cherchais une expression pour décrire mes sensations.

L'expression anglaise « what has been seen cannot be unseen » m'est venue à l'esprit sans que je sois capable d'en trouver une version française satisfaisante.

Avez-vous connaissance d'une expression pouvant exprimer la même idée en français ?

J'ai ajouté le titre du film...

> [A Serbian Film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1273235/)

Comment: Serait-il possible de savoir de quel film il s'agit? Ca pourrait aider à trouver une expression qui colle bien aux effets ressentis, plutôt que de simplement traduire une expression anglaise.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon : fait dans le spoiler.

Comment: Pas encore vu, mais ça me rappelle que c'est sur ma TOWATCH-list :)

Comment: @AlexisPigeon : si tu as le coeur (et l'estomac) bien accroché, ça passe, mais il faut être connaisseur ;)

Comment: [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/what-has-been-seen-cannot-be-unseen) dit que l'expression anglaise est récente.

Answer (score 8):

Je propose ***ce qui est vu est vu***, calqué sur « ce qui est fait est fait », pour exprimer ce que tu désignes.

Et, plus trivialement, « il est trop tard » sur un ton tragique, avec le thème dramatique de la perte de l'innocence en arrière-plan, ça te pose ton contexte.

Je ne vois rien de plus idiomatique qui soit spécifique au visionnage.

Answer (score 7):

S'il s'agit d'un contexte pénible, choquant

> Ce qu'on a vu ne peut être effacé 
> On ne peut oublier ce qu'on a vu

Comment: j'aime bien le "Ce qu'on a vu ne peut être effacé", ça se rapproche assez de l'idée de départ je trouve.

Answer (score 5):

Ce que j'ai trouvé de plus proche jusqu'à maintenant :

> J'aurais aimé ne jamais voir ce que j'ai vu

Comment: Effectivement, c'est bien vu.

Answer (score 4):

Sur un ton plaisant :
"C'est gravé dans ma mémoire à l'encre indélébile"

Answer (score 3):

En essayant de rester simple :

> Maintenant c'est trop tard, je l'ai vu.

Answer (score 2):

Je propose un simple:

> Je regrette d'avoir vu cela.

Sinon, je me souviens d'une expression de ma grand-mère qui fait référence à l'ouïe:

> Il vaut mieux entendre ça qu'être sourd...

Comment: L'inverse, peut-être, « il vaudrait mieux être sourd qu'entendre ça » ?

Answer (score 1):

Il y a l'expression

> Cachez ce sein que je ne saurais voir

Elle n'est pas du tout équivalente à la vôtre, mais il me semble qu'elle porte aussi un idée de vision engageante impossible à oublier, et elle a le mérite d'être hyper connue, en France du moins. Elle fonctionne, certes avec les seins, mais aussi très bien avec les films d'horreurs, notre libido étant ce qu'elle est.

Elle vient d'une pièce de Molière il me semble, mais on la trouve aussi [chez Victor Hugo](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99%C3%82ne_%28Victor_Hugo%29/Conduite_de_l%E2%80%99homme_vis-%C3%A0-vis_de_la_cr%C3%A9ation), on la trouve partout. Molière + Hugo, ça justifie bien quelques approximations de sens :-)

Comment: *Que je n'aurais dû savoir voir*, donc, pour répondre à la question ? ^^

Comment: Oui tout à fait ho ! ho ! ho !

Answer (score 1):

Pourquoi ne pas construire le néologisme "dévoir" sur le modèle de défaire, démettre, dédire, dévoyer, etc. "Ce qui a été vu ne peut être dévu." Je sais, c'est étrange, mais tout est question d'habitude, ou de licence poétique. Les anglophones ne se privent pas d'appliquer le préfixe "un" à toutes sortes de verbe et même de substantif qui n'ont rien demandé (par [exemple](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/wordroutes/the-un-believable-un-verb)).

Answer (score 0):

> Bon ben, ça, c'est fait...

sur un ton légèrement fataliste, et un peu dégoûté. Ca ne traduit pas du tout le côté tragique de la chose, mais plutôt l'envie de ne jamais revoir ce qui a été vu.

Comment: Dans un langage familier, oui ; sinon à déconseiller.

Comment: Ce n'est pas la même idée, il me semble : d'autres choses auraient pu avoir été faites qui pourraient être défaites (et typiquement, on pourrait employer le même *ça c'est fait* en contemplant une catastrophe qui vient d'arriver à laquelle il va s'agir, dans un futur proche, de pallier).